# jquery multiple condition statements

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have the following script

```
     else if(location.hash.substr(1,15)=="step1")
```

however I would like to extend this, by adding step2 , step3 and step4.

What is the best method to have this achieved?

Comment: There is no best method. Voted to close as not constructive. Also, this has nothing to do with jQuery. Javascript is the name of the language you are using.

Comment: just use [swith case] for simple.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
switch(location.hash.substr(1,15)){
 case "step1": ...;break;
 case "step2": ...;break;
 ...
 default: ...;
}
```

If you require an unknown number of "steps", you should probably work with a regex, and group on the number.

Comment: +1 `switch` is a great for simple control flow because it is easier to read, understand and maintain

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper approach i think besides `switch`:

```
var my_str = location.hash.substr(1,15);
if (my_str == "step1")
{
    alert('step1');
}
else if (my_str == "step2")
{
   alert('step2');
}
else if (my_str == "step3")
{
   alert('step3');
}  
else 
{
  alert('step4');
}
```

First I thought to give answer with `switch` but kippie had already gave an answer with that...So I had no option otherthan `if else` ;-)

Comment: Cannot use switch? why not?

Comment: Yes ofcourse I want to give switch case also but Kippie already given the ans with switch.....So i have to give another way

Comment: But you said "This is the proper approach"

Comment: Ok I get it. Just misunderstood your statement. My apologies..:)

Comment: Why do you run substr 3 times???

Comment: Dear @bažmegakapa i just editing it,you suggested me....anyway thanku for suggestion....once see the edit plz

Comment: @bažmegakapa still downvote..??why man...iam just editing my code...and I did it even...At the same time you told me

Comment: @gautam3164 easy. I have other things to do than waiting for you editing the answer ;). Removed the dw.

Comment: @gautam3164 Relax! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to acheive. one is use more `if else`

```
else if (location.hash.substr(1,15)=="step1") { ... }
else if (location.hash.substr(1,15)=="step2") { ... }
else if (location.hash.substr(1,15)=="step3") { ... }
else if (location.hash.substr(1,15)=="step4") { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple `if` , `else if` use switch case

```
    switch(location.hash.substr(1,15)){
       case 'step1': break;
        .
        .
        default :
         ...........
         break;

      }
```